# React.js useRef hook not returning the expected object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React hooks and I have the code below:

```js
const [_va, _setva] = useState(0);
const va = useRef({current: _va});
console.log(va);
```

So [according to the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), The expected value of `va` is an object which has a `current` property containing the desired value which is initially 0.

But when I run the script I got this result:

[image: result]

In other words, instead of the `va.current` containing the desired value, `va.current` contains another `current` property which contains the desired value. Which means I have to access `va.current.current` to access the desired value.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood the doc; you will set the value of the ref, and it is returned in the `current` property of the returned object:

```js
const ref = useRef("foo");
console.log(ref.current) // "foo"
```

The purpose of useRef is to give you an object whose reference does not change, but whose value may. That value is exposed as `current`. You can access and reassign `ref.current` at will, and `ref` remains unchanged.